# Create/populate Custom Posts ACF fields from external JSON file

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, json

So basically i have an App where users upload recipes and the data is stored in a JSON file on a third party server. What i want to do is fetch the data from the JSON file (url) every hour and use it to create and populate (if not existing) or update (existing) custom posts that have ACF fields.

Can anyone tell me:
A: is this possible or am i dreaming? :)
B: point me in the right direction as i have no idea where to start.

I know ACF pretty well but i am new to importing from JSON on an automated schedule.

Comment: I don't think there's much too it really: you'll need to 1) set up a scheduled job to run every hour; 2) fetch JSON from the server, either just changes if the remote service supports that or all JSON if not; 3) map the JSON to the set of recipe posts you already have, e.g. using fixed IDs in the JSON if possible which you can store in post meta; 4) update existing posts from the data, and make new posts with any new data; 5) optionally move any existing posts that have been deleted in the JSON to trash

Comment: that is good to know, thank you. i will try to research each of these steps.